# Docker Logging w/ Syslog container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rsyslog

## Problem

So I'm trying to get logging setup in my docker-compose setup.
Right now I am running into issues with the `app` service connecting to the `logging` service, specifically...

```
Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: dial udp: lookup ng on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 192.168.65.4:50257->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
```

I am hoping to have my app/container send all of its logs to another container that has rsyslog setup. I'm not sure if I need to specify the service as the host or something, but I can't find anything that explains how I would do it that way.

> Eventually, I want to expand the app horizontally and have all of them point at a load balancing proxy like Traefik which would pass the logs on to a number of rsyslog containers.

## Documentation

#### Command Line Output

```
    $ docker-compose up
    [+] Building 1.7s (18/18) FINISHED
     => [turbo-train_syslog-ng internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                               0.1s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 202B                                                                                     0.0s
     => [turbo-train_application internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                             0.1s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 509B                                                                                     0.0s
     => [turbo-train_syslog-ng internal] load .dockerignore                                                                  0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                          0.0s
     => [turbo-train_application internal] load .dockerignore                                                                0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                          0.0s
     => [turbo-train_syslog-ng internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                   0.0s
     => [turbo-train_syslog-ng 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                     0.0s
     => [turbo-train_syslog-ng internal] load build context                                                                  0.1s
     => => transferring context: 2.91kB                                                                                      0.0s
     => [turbo-train_application internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:latest                                 1.3s
     => CACHED [turbo-train_syslog-ng 2/3] RUN apk update && apk upgrade --available && apk add rsyslog                      0.0s
     => [turbo-train_syslog-ng 3/3] COPY conf/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.conf                                                 0.1s
     => [turbo-train_application] exporting to image                                                                         0.0s
     => => exporting layers                                                                                                  0.0s
     => => writing image sha256:<HashValue>                                                                                  0.0s
     => => naming to docker.io/library/turbo-train_syslog-ng                                                                 0.0s
     => => writing image sha256:<HashValue>                                                                                  0.0s
     => => naming to docker.io/library/turbo-train_application                                                               0.0s
     => [auth] library/golang:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                            0.0s
     => [turbo-train_application build 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/golang:latest@sha256:<HashValue>                          0.0s
     => [turbo-train_application internal] load build context                                                                0.1s
     => => transferring context: 222B                                                                                        0.0s
     => CACHED [turbo-train_application build 2/4] WORKDIR /go/src/app                                                       0.0s
     => CACHED [turbo-train_application build 3/4] COPY [ ./src/go-app.go, ./src/go.mod, /go/src/app/ ]                      0.0s
     => CACHED [turbo-train_application build 4/4] RUN go build -o go-app                                                    0.0s
     => CACHED [turbo-train_application stage-1 1/1] COPY --from=build /go/src/app/go-app /go-app                            0.0s
    
    Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
    [+] Running 3/3
     - Network turbo-train_default  Created                                                                                  0.7s
     - Container gopkg              Created                                                                                  0.3s
     - Container syslog-ng          Created                                                                                  0.3s
    Attaching to gopkg, syslog-ng
    syslog-ng  | rsyslogd 8.2012.0: running as pid 1, enabling container-specific defaults, press ctl-c to terminate rsyslog
    Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: dial udp: lookup ng on 192.168.65.5:53: read udp 192.168.65.4:50257->192.168.65.5:53: i/o timeout
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
    # docker-compose.yml
    version: '3.9'
    services:
      # Svc 1
      application:
        build:
          context: ./app
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: gopkg
        dns: 1.1.1.1
        logging:
          driver: syslog
          options:
            syslog-address: "udp://${syslog-ng}:514"
            tag: gopkg
        depends_on:
          - logging
      # Svc 2
      syslog-ng:
        build:
          context: ./syslog
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: syslog-ng
        dns: 1.1.1.1
```

#### /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
    # rsyslog configuration file
    #
    # For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
    # or latest version online at http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html
    # If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html
    
    
    #### Global directives ####
    
    # Sets the directory that rsyslog uses for work files.
    $WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
    
    # Sets default permissions for all log files.
    $FileOwner root
    $FileGroup adm
    $FileCreateMode 0640
    $DirCreateMode 0755
    $Umask 0022
    
    # Check config syntax on startup and abort if unclean (default off).
    #$AbortOnUncleanConfig on
    
    # Reduce repeating messages (default off).
    #$RepeatedMsgReduction on
    
    
    #### Modules ####
    
    # Provides --MARK-- message capability.
    module(load="immark")
    
    # Provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command).
    module(load="imuxsock")
    
    # Reads kernel messages.
    # module(load="imklog")
    
    #### Config files ####
    
    # Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/.
    include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")
    
    #### Rules ####
    
    # Log all kernel messages to kern.log.
    kern.*                                                  /var/log/kern.log
    
    # Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
    # Don't log private authentication messages!
    # NOTE: The minus sign in front of filename disables buffer flush.
    *.info;authpriv.none;cron.none;kern.none;mail.none      -/var/log/messages
    
    # The authpriv file has restricted access.
    authpriv.*                                              /var/log/auth.log
    
    # Log all the mail messages in one place.
    mail.*                                                  -/var/log/mail.log
    
    # Log cron stuff.
    cron.*                                                  -/var/log/cron.log
    
    # Everybody gets emergency messages.
    *.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
    
    # Log all kernel messages to the console.
    # Logging much else clutters up the screen.
    #kern.*                                                 /dev/console
    
    
    ### Examples ####
    
    # Send all logs to remote syslog via UDP.
    # An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
    # down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
    #*.* action(
    #       type="omfwd"
    #       target="192.168.0.1"
    #       port="514"
    #       protocol="udp"
    #       queue.filename="fwdRule1"  # unique name prefix for spool files
    #       queue.type="LinkedList"
    #       queue.maxDiskSpace="256m"
    #       queue.saveOnShutdown="on"
    #       action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
    #       action.resumeInterval="30"
    #)
    
    # Receive messages from remote host via UDP
    # for parameters see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imudp.html
    module(load="imudp")  # needs to be done just once
    input(
          type="imudp"
          port="514"
    )
```

#### Dockerfile - rsyslog (./syslog/Dockerfile)

```
    FROM alpine:latest AS syslog
    RUN apk update && apk upgrade --available && apk add rsyslog
    COPY conf/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.conf
    ENTRYPOINT ["rsyslogd", "-n"]
```

#### Dockerfile - Go App (./app/Dockerfile)

```
    # STAGE 1: Build
    FROM golang:latest AS build
    WORKDIR /go/src/app
    COPY [ "./src/go-app.go", "./src/go.mod", "/go/src/app/" ]
    RUN go build -o go-app
    
    # -------------------------------------------------
    # STAGE 2: Deployment
    FROM scratch
    COPY --from=build /go/src/app/go-app /go-app
    ENTRYPOINT [ "/go-app" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error you are getting is due to not being able to reference another container in in the logging driver syslog-address (see similar issues [here](https://docker-user.narkive.com/NgeomFHp/syslog-address-in-compose-doesn-t-allow-container-hostname) and [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2657)). Also I don't think you need to send the logs to syslog in the go app as well, it should be doing a regular logging to stdout.

One of the solutions could be to run a syslog and expose its syslog port and then point syslog-address to host.docker.internal.

Here is my example (well, slightly modified your example), also [here](https://github.com/jabbson/q70029248) to clone.

### Folder structure:

```
 ~/Projects/docker/log-test  tree
.
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── src
│       ├── go-app.go
│       └── go.mod
├── docker-compose.yml
└── syslog
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── conf
        └── rsyslog.conf
```

### app/Dockerfile

```
unmodified
```

### app/src/go-app.go

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  for i := 0; i < 1000; i ++ {
    fmt.Printf("Log Entry #%d\n", i)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
  }
}
```

### syslog/Dockerfile

```
unmodified
```

### syslog/conf/rsyslog.conf

```
unmodified
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  application:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: gopkg
    dns: 1.1.1.1
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "udp://host.docker.internal:5514"
        tag: gopkg
    depends_on:
      - syslog-ng

  syslog-ng:
    build:
      context: ./syslog
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: syslog-ng
    dns: 1.1.1.1
    ports:
    - "5514:514/udp"
```

### Verifying:

```
docker compose up -d
[+] Running 3/3
 ⠿ Network log-test_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 ⠿ Container syslog-ng       Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.5s
 ⠿ Container gopkg           Started
```

```
docker compose exec syslog-ng tail /var/log/messages
2021-11-19T05:35:56+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #47
2021-11-19T05:35:57+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #48
2021-11-19T05:35:58+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #49
2021-11-19T05:35:59+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #50
2021-11-19T05:36:00+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #51
2021-11-19T05:36:01+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #52
2021-11-19T05:36:02+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #53
2021-11-19T05:36:03+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #54
2021-11-19T05:36:04+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #55
2021-11-19T05:36:05+00:00 192.168.0.1 gopkg[1452]: Log Entry #56
```

While this works, the easier solution would be to switch back to using syslog logging in the go code, and point the logger to that other container instead of doing it through the logging driver.